# Qt signals and slots trouble

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have 2 classes:

```
class Server : public QTcpServer
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Server(QObject * parent = 0 , quint16 port = 1922);
void SendData(QString data);
virtual ~Server();
signals:
void RecieveMessage(QString);

private slots:
void acceptConnection();
void startRead();
void disconnected();

private:
QTcpServer *tcpServer;
QTcpSocket *client;
};
```

and

```
class ChessLanTEst : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
friend class Server;
friend class Client;
ChessLanTEst(QWidget *parent = 0);
~ChessLanTEst();

private:
Ui::ChessLanTEstClass ui;
Server *server_;
Client *client_;
private slots:
void createGame();
void ShowMessage(QString);
};
```

in Server class I have signal:

```
void RecieveMessage(QString);
```

in ChessLanTEst class I have slot:

```
   void ShowMessage(QString);
```

and I connected it in the ChessLanTEst  constructor:

```
connect(server_, &Server::RecieveMessage, this, &ChessLanTEst::ShowMessage);
```

but I don't receive this signal and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you get a message at runtime?

Comment: Check return value of `connect`. Make sure (with breakpoint or debug prints) that you really emit the signal.

Comment: And makes sure `server_` is valid pointer, initialized and not `nullptr`. Also, are you sure you are using Qt5?

Comment: emit RecieveMessage("emit here");
i emit it in the constructor of the Server class

Comment: and it really emit
[screen](http://screenshot.su/show.php?img=3184f983f125908e781e223f326ef68a.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments, you emit in constructor of `server_`, *before* you do `connect` (because constructor has returned if you have valid value in `server_` pointer).

Emits themselves are not queued ever, connect must have been done before emit for the slot to be called (or the call queued).

Comment: exactly! I don't think about this case

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the SIGNAL and SLOT macros. Like:

```
connect(server_, SIGNAL(RecieveMessage(QString)), this, SLOT(ShowMessage(QString)));
```

If you search for the definitions of these macro's, you'll find that the arguments are actually converted to strings.

Comment: The question seems to be using the new Qt5 overload of `connect`, so this should not be an issue. But worth trying, to perhaps get runtime error message with debug build.

Comment: Did you properly declare the ShowMessage function as a slot: ? Posting the complete class definitions could help find the problem